# Git: как клонировать только 1 файл

Tags: git

Возможно ли такое? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 3):

Используй силу [git archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html#_examples) юный падаван.

```
git archive --remote=http://bittracker.org/someproject.git HEAD:<path/to/directory/or/file> <filename> | tar -x
```

И ещё [несколько вариантов](https://gist.github.com/ssp/1663093).

Comment: написал  git archive --remote=http://github.com/repo777/index.git HEAD:class/Sql.php class/Sql.php | tar -x - получил ошибку fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch
git checkout -m <revision> <yourfilepath>
git add <yourfilepath>
git commit
```

Забираем фетчем код, делаем чекаут по номеру коммита (revision) и нужному пути файла, и добавляем новым коммитом.

Также есть команда `git archive`, которая тоже позволяет такое сделать. Подробней читайте здесь - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive.